# SCSS problem: Unable to keep sass watch running

Tags: sass, watch

I've been having a very annoying problem lately.

Every time I run the command "sass --watch scss:css" the scss compiles the code but returns the error:
Unexpected exception:
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch

This problem did not occur before and due to lack of information I am having difficulties to correct it.
Every time I need to turn scss into css I can but I need to run the command every time because it stops watching.
Any clues?

Here is the console:

PS X:\Trabalho\PrintOne\Loja_Modelo_2013\Tecnologia\Desenvolvimento\novaLoja\assets> sass --watch scss:css
Compiled scss\imports.scss to css\imports.css.
Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.

Unexpected exception:
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch

Comment: Without clear knowledge of your environment, your Sass version or your code, it’s hard to help. If you think this is a bug with Sass, it might be more effective to report it to the project: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues
Don’t forget to include clear steps on how to reproduce the issue.